# Branch.IO Unpopulated or Null Installs

Tags: branch.io

Im a student and just learning the ropes in particular using Branch. Does anyone know what Null or Unpopulated installs could mean, and why they started off with a count of 0 and suddenly increased?

Screenshot of branch.io dashboard:

[image: Screenshot of branch.io dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see Unpopulated data on the Dashboard if the corresponding field is not being attributed. Let's say you have a link(Quick Link or Ad Link) and have not mentioned analytical tags, then though the Installs/Events will get attributed to the link but the channel/campaign if you haven't mentioned will be Unpopulated.

On Branch's end you can utilise Dashboard's LiveView Feature to see the real-time data-flow to Branch Servers via SDK to verify the recording of particular Test App Install/Open. If you require more debugging with this please reach out to "support@branch.io"